# How to change position on list (<ul>) when website is scrolling

Tags: jquery

On my website I have vertical unsorted list as dots. After clicking on an `<li>` the webpage scrolls to adequate anchor, but when website is scrolling for example by whell dots are not moved. How to resolve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: fiddle pls. So that we can help you

Comment: you will need to use a "Scroll Spy" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-think your logic in order to mark each bullet as "active". Listen for the `scroll` event and determine which headline is the closest one to the current viewport - mark that one as `active`.

For example:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var $headlines = $('h1'); //assuming your headlines are h1-tags

    // get the closest headline
    var closestIndex,
        closestOffset=null;
    for (var i=0; i<$headlines.length; i++){
        if (closestOffset===null || Math.abs(scrollPosition-$($headlines[i]).offset().top) < closestOffset){
            closestIndex=i;
        }
    }

    // mark as active
    if (!$headlines[closestIndex].classList.contains('active'))
        $headlines[closestIndex].classList.add('active');
});
```

Untested. Just POC. You might want to add `window.offsetHeight/2` to the `scrollPosition` - that is the center of the current viewport.